# Seg Fault Issue C++ (file IO / getline)

Tags: c++, file-io, segmentation-fault, getline

I am having an issue pertaining to receiving a segmentation fault which is coming from somewhere within one of these 3 portions of my code presumably. I have tried different debuggiing tactics of adding cout's to see which point the code is getting screwed up to no avail. Any and all help will greatly be appreciated.

```
void agency::readAllData()
{
    int index;
    char inputFile[100];
    char delim = '}';
    car * p_car;
    p_car = m_inventory;
    cout << "Input file name: " << endl ;
    cin >> inputFile;
    ifstream input (inputFile);
    if (input)
    {
        input >> m_name >> m_zipcode;
        for (index = 0; index < 5; index++)
        {
            int tempYear, tempAvailable;
            float tempPrice;
            char tempMake[256], tempModel[256], tempSensors[256], tempOwner[256];
            input >> tempYear >> tempMake >> tempModel >> tempPrice;
            input.getline(tempSensors, 256, delim);
            input >> tempAvailable;
            if (tempAvailable = 0);
            {
                input >> tempOwner;
            }
            p_car -> readCars(tempYear, tempMake, tempModel, tempPrice, tempSensors, tempAvailable, tempOwner);
            p_car++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Input file cannot be opened" << endl;
        return;
    }
    return;
}

void sensor::readSensors(char tempSensors[], sensor *sensor_ptr)
{
    int index1;
    int index2 = 0;
    int index3 = 0;
    for(index1 = 0; tempSensors[index2] != '\0'; index1++)
    {
        if (tempSensors[index1] = 'g')
        {
            gpsCount++;
        }
        else if (tempSensors[index1] = 'l')
        {
            lidarCount++;
        }
        else if (tempSensors[index1] = 'r')
        {
            radarCount++;
        }
        else if (tempSensors[index1] = 'c')
        {
            cameraCount++;
        }
        for(index2+=index1; tempSensors[index2] != ' '; index2++)
        {
            sensor_ptr->m_type[index3] = tempSensors[index2];
            index3++;
        }
        sensor_ptr++;
    }
    return;
}
```

these functions exist among seperate files but interact in the order I have pasted them.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `std::string`, or is `char *` a requirement of the assignment?

Comment: We are prohibited from using std::string.

Comment: The shown code in this question fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone on stackoverflow.com will be able to help you. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that anyone can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce your problem (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly***. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It likely comes with a very good debugger. @Sam has a really good copy-paste explanation of the importance of using a debugger.

Comment: What helps other people to help is to minimize your problem as @SamVarshavchik proposed. When people do that - it usually results in a response in minutes. Complicated cases takes longer for sure, but this is not one of them.

Comment: As a software development productivity aid debuggers are second only to the compiler. Learn to use the debugger. It takes a bit of time to get familiar, but afterwards it's time you can use to pass other courses, hang with your friends, and pown newbs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile, since it's neither a minimal example nor the complete set of code.

Without analyzing it deeply, this line seems fishy:

```cpp
if (tempAvailable = 0);
```

It shouldn't compile at all and also you are assigning 0 to `tempAvailable`.

Especially with segfaults using debuggers is far better than doing print debugging.

I suggest looking for tutorials on `gdb`. Another option is trying to compile the code with address sanitization (just google for it).